# How to avoid the double non-nullable check in TypeScript discriminated unions?

Tags: typescript

In below code TypeScript does not believe that if `customMessage` is `undefined`, `className` is NOT `undefined`:

```js
export default class ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError extends Error {

  public static readonly NAME: string = "ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError";

  public constructor(
      parametersObject: {
        customMessage: string;
        className?: undefined;
      } | {
        className: string;
        customMessage?: undefined;
      }
  ) {

    super();

    this.name = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.NAME;

    if (typeof parametersObject.customMessage !== "undefined") {
      this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
    } else {
      this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
          className: parametersObject.className
      })
    }
  }

  private static buildMessage(parametersObject: { className: string }): string {
    return `The class '${parametersObject.className}' has not been executed;`
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwvkQErACO6AllMAgJIB2dMdqmdAXqpwisAEoQByEGACFgwVgFEQwHOhhN5UKNDig1rBMQ1aocAN4BYAFBW4cMOgBGPHHAIwBdF41QIhmAJ5wYgCCALLyAFyuMFB0rADmcAC8cABEZIQEVLQMTGwcXDz8giLikjJyisqq6prQqQDcVjZ2js5wOEJuUOg4MNAAFC22tmCoUKgAtsBqUAQA8g4AVsowURaWI1sd6G4Qk6HARKjxwFHdcfFNm9u2eJliU8AA-FHo+ihxTNe3AL5wAB8zMNtvciI9pucYpcfrcdnsDkcCCcXm8PsgvghYVtfi0AJTA6w3WwEdBgYBQAZ464gmAACzoBAAdKwnslSOQsjR6IwWOxONw+B4hKICBJpLIFEoVGoEEZoEyQuEacS4HRkHABjB-OSIBqxhNprMFstVkyVAjDsdTnAAIRJFKpd5IDGsJipAkbW70xlM6bW4Dsg1PY2LFZ9c27fqIgPYuD-YCYAiBr3bH3M-3Im0pDKUbm5PkFQXFOgisoSyrSmpyupQJkOeiYBBWrPAAapuEdTkQs52cYhikm8Mwc3dp4g2y-PEg3E3WctMCxABuAkDbg8LgbdCbLZRA2DRsHYdW6y7DyeUNiCXjeMvl0JW0YMHQUFYcAABgAVOmBsHEADkAAkpgHjMR6mhGf49r8-5wHShBwKwkhwA4ko6FWsoNO+LSzrOQA)

Error:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

I know that if will make the double check like:

```js
if (typeof parametersObject.customMessage !== "undefined") {
    this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
} else if (typeof parametersObject.className !== "undefined") {
    this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
        className: parametersObject.className
})
```

above example will work, but:

1. I want to avoid `else if (typeof parametersObject.className !== "undefined")` if possible
2. Event left it, TypeScript will not believe that one of `customMessage` or `className` has been initlized. Here is the example when it's critical:

```js
let message: string;

if (typeof parametersObject.customMessage !== "undefined") {
    message = parametersObject.customMessage;
} else if (typeof parametersObject.className !== "undefined") {
    message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
        className: parametersObject.className
    })
}

console.log(message.length)
```

```
Variable 'message' is used before being assigned.(2454)
```

**Please note** that this question is about how to make TypeScript believe that if `customMessage` is `undefined`, `className` is NOT undefined and vice versa, not how to initialize `this.message` (the `ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError` class is just for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 parametersObject: {
        customMessage: string;
        className?: undefined;
      } | {
        className: string;
        customMessage?: undefined;
      }
```

could be simplified to:

```
parametersObject: {
        customMessage: string;
      } | {
        className: string;
      }
```

as `property?: undefined` brings pretty no additional information.

Then the condition could be expressed as:

```
if ('customMessage' in parametersObject) {
  this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
} else {
  this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
      className: parametersObject.className
  })
}
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=5&pln=23&pc=6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwvkQErACO6AllMAgJIB2dMdqmdAXqpwisAEoQByEGACFgwVgFEQwHOhhN5UKNDig1rBMQ1aocAN4BYAFBW4cMOgBGPHHAIwBdF41QIhmAJ5wYgCCALLyAFyuMFB0rADmcAC8cABEZIQEVLQMTGwcXDz8giLikjJyisqq6prQqQDcVjZ2js5wOEJuUOg4MNAAFC22tmCoUKgAtsBqUAQA8g4AVsowURaWI1sd6G4Qk6HARKjxwFHdcfFNm9sAvnAAPmbD23iZYlNn0bEJ19twtxaAEpntYbrYCOgwMAoAMgdcXjAABZ0AgAOlYn2SpHIWRo9EYLHYnG4fA8QlEBAk0lkCiUKjUCCM0DRIXCCPBcDoyDgAwA5Co9gcjgQTsA+VzWHZxp9ZgtlqsQRt-sjUWjpsdTtixhNpnLFis+mjBf1hZrgH8RvdgJgCMBQSqUeiNaKtSkMpR8bkiQVScU6BSyjTKvSaky6lA0Q56JgEIdzQNlf8Rm8iB9plEdbKYfLDTBjbj08AXrZbkCXoCbpWWmBYgA3AT2tweFzRuix+Ou4ADLN6nMG1brDqFz7nGKXAFAsc-RJJ2yMGDoKBSgAGABUkfbU8Q+QASUy9mb9hVG7dF24SpGEOCsSRwBy0nShxkNFctSuVoA)

#### UPDATE

To strictly force one option or another:

```
type Params<T extends {
        customMessage: string;
      } | {
        className: string;
      }>  = T extends {
        customMessage: any;
        className: any;
      }  ? never : T

export default class ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError<P extends {
        customMessage: string;
      } | {
        className: string;
      }> extends Error {

  public static readonly NAME: string = "ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError";

  public constructor(
      parametersObject: P extends Params<P> ? P : never
  ) {

    super();

    this.name = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.NAME;

    if ('customMessage' in parametersObject) {
      this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
    } else {
      this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
          className: parametersObject.className
      })
    }
  }

  private static buildMessage(parametersObject: { className: string }): string {
    return `The class '${parametersObject.className}' has not been executed;`
  }
}

new ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError({ customMessage: ''  }) // ok
new ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError({ className: ''  }) // ok
new ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError({ customMessage: '', className: ''  }) // error as expected
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=115&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4AqUIA9gQB2AJqlAN4CwAUFHfXQMYCuqwA9sgLISqpwBzCAC4obBAEtCAgNw0GdAL5QAPhXkKmAGzh8AcihFjgk6XNoLFAPjoBeKNjwESZKhc0s2nHn0FG4hCDmmtq6qAbI-oHBlnQA-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-IoFYeroiQLFAsKJscKbbDIdGgTQYE0EkADuQZUm0oZ0hGjLRiycbzIenJSTyZ7SjhI7IfcUCFhWxFQAA9HZUDsAA1opEAqWuzTqZu9KRkyMasvGBlJlyqbGRC964T8+HWUodoOTgJlQMJuRat0bkecG3lhr52m7vuQUciFRmnhFZmsNcFlGNZAA0UXPpEoixbZCVpBCyVkKlErdEAA)

Comment: Very clean! Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I just noticed that user can specify both `customMessage` and `className` in constructor's parameter object and TypeScript will not emit the error... Can we prevent it somehow?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD it is possible; I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof parametersObject.customMessage` only discriminates over the type of `parametersObject.customMessage` but not over `parametersObject` - which *kinda* makes sense when you think about it as a function: `typeof(parametersObject.customMessage)`

You can better visualize this when you inspect the inferred types in the following example ([Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBYAUIxAHAQwCcCBbALkQG9tdcA3AgGwEZKBnKImMAcwG5adRkwBMlMCFIAjAKZFBORAF9EAH2pCGzNokkz5iuohHjEnbnyMrsASk1KYwRGigBPPLLjPCJUgDoRFkQAXjDEACJ9OSII+xolXAB6JPxiMkCdRBh2RAATHIhuUh4CKFk8xCg4Ko9ZPSkYrUQUxAAhAFUAFUpfMmzcgCpOGCYmQdrPZtaHYxntVg4uHgETZjNo+WnUlXVZunm1xYaDBSOzCxXt3GVt6-YavoDTAeywYHkiCqqa909EAAGlz4e02RABzSemTE1lwXygICISChQWsqlkTHY9QSc1SKJ0S0svGu+LEhJWoMaW0SaT80NEsMQ8MRyPSzx0aOwyiAA)):

```
function foo(
  param: {
    val1: string;
    val2: number;
  } | {
    val1: number;
    val2: string;
  }
) {
  if (typeof param.val1 === "number") {
    // param.val1 is discriminated to type number
    // BUT: param is *still* type
    //  {
    //    val1: string; val2: number
    //  } | {
    //    val1: number; val2: string
    //  }
    //
    // so param.val2 is inferred to type `string | number`
    param.val2;
    return param.val1;
  } else {
    // param.val1: string
    // param.val2: string | number
    param.val2;
    return param.val1;
  }
}
```

Although in the `if` branch TypeScript can discriminate `param.val1` to be a `number` it **does not** infer `param` to be `{val1: number; val2: string;}`.
The `else` branch is just the other way around: `param.val1` is correctly inferred to be a `string` but `param` is still inferred as `{val1: number; val2: string;}`.

Because of this in both cases `param.val2` can not be narrowed down and is inferred as `string | number`.

---

Instead of `typeof` you could use a equality comparison `parametersObject.customMessage !== undefined` which is then able to correctly infer the type of `parametersObject` as well ([Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwvkQErACO6AllMAgJIB2dMdqmdAXqpwisAEoQByEGACFgwVgFEQwHOhhN5UKNDig1rBMQ1aocAN4BYAFBW4cMOgBGPHHAIwBdF41QIhmAJ5wYgCCALLyAFyuMFB0rADmcAC8cABEZIQEVLQMTGwcXDz8giLikjJyisqq6prQqQDcVjZ2js5wOEJuUOg4MNAAFC22tmCoUKgAtsBqUAQA8g4AVsowURaWI1sd6G4Qk6HARKjxwFHdcfFNm9u2eJliU8AA-FHo+ihxTNe3AL5wAB8zMNtvciI9pucYpcfrcdnsDkcCCcXm8PsgvghYVtfi0AJTA6w3WwEdBgYBQAZ464gmAACzoBAAdKwnslSOQsjR6IwWOxONw+B4hKICBJpLIFEoVGoEEZoEyQuEacS4HRkHABmMJtNZgtlqsmSoEYdjqc4ABCJIpd5IDGsJgEja3emMpnTM3Adnap56xYrPpG3b9RGe7Fwf7ATAEL3O7au5ke5HmlIZSjc3J8gqC4p0EVlCWVaU1OV1KBMhz0TAIU3J4ADONwjqciFnOzjX0U-UBmBGltPEG2X54kG4m5jlpgWIANwEXrcHhclbo1drKK1Hd1Xf9q3WzYeTyhsQSEbxR8uhK2jBg6CgrDgAAMACp0r1g4gAcgAJKYfVu5jugbvq2vwfnAdKEHArCSHADiSjoxayg0D4tGOY5AA)):

```
if (parametersObject.customMessage !== undefined) {
  this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
} else {
  this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
      className: parametersObject.className
  })
}
```

If the objects passed to your constructor not actually contain the optional parameters it might be better though to follow [artur grzesiak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855805/how-to-avoid-the-double-non-nullable-check-in-typescript-discriminated-unions/65901136#65901136): drop the optional keys from the type and use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) in the condition ([Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwvkQErACO6AllMAgJIB2dMdqmdAXqpwisAEoQByEGACFgwVgFEQwHOhhN5UKNDig1rBMQ1aocAN4BYAFBW4cMOgBGPHHAIwBdF41QIhmAJ5wYgCCALLyAFyuMFB0rADmcAC8cABEZIQEVLQMTGwcXDz8giLikjJyisqq6prQqQDcVjZ2js5wOEJuUOg4MNAAFC22tmCoUKgAtsBqUAQA8g4AVsowURaWI1sd6G4Qk6HARKjxwFHdcfFNm9sAvnAAPmbD23iZYlNn0bEJ19twtxaAEpntYbrYCOgwMAoAMgdcXjAABZ0AgAOlYn2SpHIWRo9EYLHYnG4fA8QlEBAk0lkCiUKjUCCM0DRIXCCPBcDoyDgAwA5Co9gcjgQTsA+VzWHZxp9ZgtlqsQRt-sjUWjpsdTtixhNpnLFis+mjBf1hZrgH8RvdgJgCMBQSqUeiNaKtSkMpR8bkiQVScU6BSyjTKvSaky6lA0Q56JgEIdzQNlf8Rm8iB9plEdbKYfLDTBjbj08AXrZbkCXoCbpWWmBYgA3AT2tweFzRuix+Ou4ADLN6nMG1brDqFz7nGKXAFAsc-RJJ2yMGDoKBSgAGABUkfbU8Q+QASUy9mb9hVG7dF24SpGEOCsSRwBy0nShxkNFctSuVoA)):

```
  public constructor(
      parametersObject: {
        customMessage: string;
      } | {
        className: string;
      }
  ) {

    super();

    this.name = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.NAME;

    if ('customMessage' in parametersObject) {
      this.message = parametersObject.customMessage;
    } else {
      this.message = ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.buildMessage({
          className: parametersObject.className
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I am so sorry about can not give the reputation prize to more than one answerer...